# Any better way than using setInterval() to detect a class variable changes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I monitor changes of a class variable from its instance?

I can achieve the goal with `setInterval()` but the code becomes not human-readable at all.

```
let calibrator = new Calibrator("hardwareName");
calibrator.connect();

let monitoring = setInterval(() => {
    if (calibrator.getState()) { // calibrator.getState() will become true when there's response from hardware.
        clearInterval(monitoring);
        // lots of logic here
    } else {
        // lots of logic here
    }
}, 0);
```

I expected anyone by just simply read the code can easily know that I'm trying to monitor a class variable. But `clearInterval()` is nothing related to this in term of the high-level logic.

So I want a better approach for doing this.

Comment: Will there be any user interaction or additional calls? What causes the variable to change?

Comment: "brrr" `setInterval(fn, 0)` is bad, don't do it please. Besides, what is your relation with this class? Are you its author? If so, how come you can't just put some logic in what causes the change to let your other code know it has changed?

Comment: @Kaiido those logic do nothing related to the class, and the variable will be changed when there's some hardware response.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There is an API for `Mutation Observer`.  You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
// The DOM node to observe
const target = document.getElementById("your-id");

// Callback function when changes occurs
function callback(mutationRecord, observer) {}

// Create a new instance of MutationObserver with callback in params
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Setup config
const config = {
  childList: true
};

// When everything is ready, we just observe our target
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest Event triggering but this is better

Comment: This works very well for html elements, but the OP stated he wanted to monitor a variable

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 0;
  }
  incrementBar() {  
    this.bar++;
  }
}

const handler = {
  set: (target, prop, val) => {
    console.log('prop:', prop, ' changed to:', val);
    target[prop] = val;
    return true;
  }
}


const obj = new Proxy(new Foo(), handler);

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  obj.fooo = i;
  obj.incrementBar();
}
```

Comment: Won't work. They want to monitor the object. If they are not responsible of the changes, then there is no way they can set the proxy's properties instead of the original object's. And if they can change the code that does modify the original object so it uses the Proxy instead... then they don't need to monitor it.

Comment: @Kaiido the set *is* monitoring the object (class instance)...that's what `target` is. The set is listening for any changes on that target

Comment: No you don't get me... Let's say in *some-plugin.js* `export const foo = {bar: 'baz' }; setTimeout(()=>foo.bar = 'blah', )`. Then in *main.js*, `import foo from 'some-plugin'; obj = new Proxy(foo, ...)` Your proxy won't catch the change. For this to work, every code that does modify the original object should instead use the Proxy, but at this rythm, it's also just as clear to do `dispatchEvent('I Changed it')`.

Comment: @Kaiido neither of us knows how OP is declaring the class instance

Comment: Of course it does. If Op creates the instance they can do what they want with it

Comment: @Kaiido agree it may not work in all cases but no real details were provided